# Understanding Gitosis user repo access

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, gitosis

I have set up `git` and `gitosis` at my Ubuntu v-server. Creating new repositories on the server, checking out `gitosis-admin.git` and pushing an altered conf and new keys (`otheruser.pub` for example) works fine. The `authorized_keys` file gets updated as well. But now I got stuck.

If I try to push an existing (locale machine) repository to a bare repository on the `myserver.com` with a different user then '`git`' it doesn't work.

Example (SSH):

```
git@myserver.com:/my/path/to/xyzrepo.git
```

works, but

```
otheruser@myserver.com:/my/path/to/xyzrepo.git
```

doesn't...

I assumed that gitosis creates temp users or something similar on the machine. Is that correct?

Comment: Please try to understand how Gitolite user access works, not gitosis (dead project for 3 years now): http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/users.html: those are purely ssh-authenticated users (not actual user accounts on the server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `gitosis` you always use the same userid (`git`@...). You are identified by the ssh key you're using.  You'll note that commericial Git hosting services like [GitHub](http://github.com/) and [Gitorious](http://gitorious.com/) work the same way.

I want to highlight djs's comment: you should not be able to log into the `git` user account with a password.  Gitosis relies on the ssh `authorized_keys` files to operate correctly, and this is only used when someone authenticates using ssh keys.

Comment: hm okay... then I wonder how I could push something to the repository in the first place. I haven't set the corresponding key on my client machine but used an auto generated key ^^_^^ :( How can I forbid access to people who have the git user ssh password but must not have access to my repositories?

Comment: There shouldn't be a password for the git user at all. Public key authentication only. On another note, take a look at [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) instead of gitosis. Gitolite is well-maintained and documented, in contrast to gitosis (which inspired it, but is inactive).

Comment: The git user is basically a stand-in for all the other users. It's the one that has access to the repositories, but it stores the other keys in "authorized keys" and uses them to give access to the repos. It's kind of weird and takes a bit of getting used to, but that's how it works -- you always use the "git" user.